# JSP page using JSTL fails with exception

Tags: jsp, web, jetty, osgi, jstl

I've inherited a mass of old Java Web code that is replete with security issues. I am trying to use jstl (c:out) to address some of the issues caused by using a simple out.println().

This Java Web Code is not based on any recent/modern framework. It's essentially raw servlet code. It's using the Jetty Web server (version 9.3), which is started as an OSGI bundle. The Web Interface consists of multiple separate web applications deployed with .WAR files, and I'm just focusing one of them.

I included the taglib directive at the top of the problematic jsp file as follows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

The first time I go to the jsp page, I see the following in the jetty log:

```
2019-01-08 20:44:44,606 qtp1697835528-134 WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler  -

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/applicationsChoice.jsp(1,63) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
            at ...
```

Now, I've seen other posts on this topic that say you must include the jstl jar file (version 1.2.x)  in the webapps WEB-INF/lib directory. Initially this was not done for this webapp. So, I did that, rebuilt then redeployed the WAR file. However, I get the same error/exception when I navigate to the jsp page. I've also checked the jar files for Jetty and they include the many of the jstl entries.

This is my first exposure to Java Web Dev and I'm stumped on what to do or try. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Updating my question with the web.xml file... For the record, I've tried a few different changes to the web.xml file, with the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!--
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_5.dtd">
-->

    <web-app version="2.5">
      <!--
       <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
       id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
       -->

        <display-name>Installation process</display-name>
        <description>
          This is version 1.0 of the installation process
          based on JSP pages.
        </description>

        <session-config>
          <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>    <!-- 30 minutes -->
        </session-config>

        <!--welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>jsp/install.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list-->

        <error-page>
          <error-code>403</error-code>
          <location>/deny</location>
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
          <error-code>404</error-code>
          <location>/notFound</location>
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
          <error-code>500</error-code>
          <location>/internalError</location>
        </error-page>

        <error-page>
          <error-code>503</error-code>
          <location>/serviceUnavail</location>
        </error-page>

        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>



    <!-- Import the common error servlets -->
        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Deny</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.alcatel.as.webadmin.common.servlet.errors.Deny</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Deny</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/deny</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>NotFound</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.alcatel.as.webadmin.common.servlet.errors.NotFound404</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>NotFound</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/notFound</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>InternalError</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.alcatel.as.webadmin.common.servlet.errors.InternalError500</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>InternalError</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/internalError</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>ServiceUnavail</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.alcatel.as.webadmin.common.servlet.errors.ServiceUnavail503</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>ServiceUnavail</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/serviceUnavail</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Import the common login servlet -->
        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.alcatel.as.webadmin.common.servlet.login.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
         <servlet>
                 <servlet-name>Doc</servlet-name>
                         <servlet-class>com.alcatel_lucent.doc.DocServlet</servlet-class>
                                 <load-on-startup/>
                                          </servlet>
    <servlet>
                 <servlet-name>View</servlet-name>
                                      <servlet-class>com.alcatel_lucent.doc.ViewServlet</servlet-class>
                                                                   <load-on-startup/>

                              </servlet>

           <!-- The following servlet-mapping maps the servlet called SampleServlet1 (see the servlet element)
                    to a url-pattern of "foo". The url-pattern is used when requesting this servlet, for example:
                         http://host:port/myWebApp/foo. -->
          <servlet-mapping>
                  <servlet-name>Doc</servlet-name>
                          <url-pattern>doc</url-pattern>
                                </servlet-mapping>
                           <servlet-mapping>
                                         <servlet-name>View</servlet-name>
                                                               <url-pattern>view</url-pattern>

                </servlet-mapping>

        <security-constraint>
          <display-name>Installation Licence Constraint</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>Licence Area</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/licenseSetup.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/licenseSetupS.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/licenseViewer.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/copyLicense.jsp</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
             <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
             <role-name>manager</role-name>
             <role-name>license</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

        <security-constraint>
          <display-name>Installation Add/update products Constraint</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>Product Area</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/applicationsChoice.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/generateIdx.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/updateBase.jsp</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
             <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
             <role-name>manager</role-name>
             <role-name>product</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

        <security-constraint>
          <display-name>Installation slave Constraint</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>slave Area</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/slaveBaseSetup.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/slaveBaseSetupS.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/startSlaveBase.jsp</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
             <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
             <role-name>manager</role-name>
             <role-name>slavedb</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <security-constraint>
          <display-name>Installation HA Constraint</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>HA Area</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/haSetup.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/haSetupS.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/haDeploy.jsp</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
             <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
             <role-name>manager</role-name>
             <role-name>ha</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

        <security-constraint>
          <display-name>Installation Add/update hosts Constraint</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>Add/update hosts Area</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/hostsChoice.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/addHost.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/hostsChoiceS.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/discoverSetupS.jsp</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
             <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
             <role-name>manager</role-name>
             <role-name>hosts</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

        <security-constraint>
          <display-name>Installation Documentation Constraint</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>Documentation Area</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/viewDoc.jsp</url-pattern>
             <url-pattern>/doc</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
             <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
             <role-name>manager</role-name>
             <role-name>docs</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <security-constraint>
          <display-name>Installation Security Constraint</display-name>
          <web-resource-collection>
             <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
             <url-pattern>/jsp/*</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
             <!-- Anyone with one of the listed roles may access this area -->
             <role-name>*</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>

        <login-config>
          <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
          <realm-name>asr-admin</realm-name>
          <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login</form-error-page>
          </form-login-config>
        </login-config>

       <security-role>
         <role-name>license</role-name>
       </security-role>
       <security-role>
         <role-name>product</role-name>
       </security-role>

       <security-role>
         <role-name>slavedb</role-name>
       </security-role>
       <security-role>
         <role-name>ha</role-name>
       </security-role>
       <security-role>
         <role-name>hosts</role-name>
       </security-role>
       <security-role>
         <role-name>docs</role-name>
       </security-role>

       <security-role>
         <role-name>subadministrator</role-name>
       </security-role>

    </web-app>
```

Please keep in mind that I didn't create or structure this project/code, and I don't understand how OSGI interacts with this, but in the parent directory to the project, there's also a a webdefault.xml file and a webdoc.xml file. The directory structure is as follows:

```
../Install/install
    -> webdefault.xml
    -> webdoc.xml
    -> WEB-INF/
         -> lib/jstl-1.2.jar (I recently added this here -- doesn't help)
         -> web.xml
```

Here are the webdefault.xml and webdoc.xml files

webdefault.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- Diffs Nokia/Jetty:                                                    -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- * set default session timeout "-5555" to be able to use the value     -->
<!--   of the callout agent as default value                               -->
<!--   see DistributedSessionManager.defineUseOfDefaultTimeout()           -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- * JspServlet                                                          -->
<!--   development = false                                                 -->
<!--   reloading   = false                                                 -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- This file contains the default descriptor for web applications.       -->
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<!-- The intent of this descriptor is to include jetty specific or common  -->
<!-- configuration for all webapps.   If a context has a webdefault.xml    -->
<!-- descriptor, it is applied before the contexts own web.xml file        -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- A context may be assigned a default descriptor by:                    -->
<!--  + Calling WebApplicationContext.setDefaultsDescriptor                -->
<!--  + Passed an arg to addWebApplications                                -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- This file is used both as the resource within the jetty.jar (which is -->
<!-- used as the default if no explicit defaults descriptor is set) and it -->
<!-- is copied to the etc directory of the Jetty distro and explicitly     -->
<!-- by the jetty.xml file.                                                -->
<!--                                                                       -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->

<web-app
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   metadata-complete="true"
   version="2.5">

  <description>
    Default web.xml file.
    This file is applied to a Web application before it's own WEB_INF/web.xml file
  </description>

-- stuff removed for brevity -- unless you think it's important
</web-app>
```

Here's the webdoc.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   metadata-complete="true"
   version="2.5">

  <description>
    Default web.xml file.
    This file is applied to a Web application before it's own WEB_INF/web.xml file
  </description>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.NoTLDJarPattern</param-name>
    <param-value>start.jar|ant-.*\.jar|dojo-.*\.jar|jetty-.*\.jar|jsp-api-.*\.jar|junit-.*\.jar|servlet-api-.*\.jar|dnsns\.jar|rt\.jar|jsse\.jar|tools\.jar|sunpkcs11\.jar|sunjce_provider\.jar|xerces.*\.jar</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet id="jsp">
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logVerbosityLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>development</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>checkInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>5</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>reloading</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>keepgenerated</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!--
    <init-param>
        <param-name>classpath</param-name>
        <param-value>?</param-value>
    </init-param>
    -->
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.JSP</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.JSPF</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.JSPX</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.XSP</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>invoker</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Invoker</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>verbose</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>nonContextServlets</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>dynamicParam</param-name>
      <param-value>anyValue</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

   .. some constraint stuff and other miscellaneous stuff removed for brevity ..
</web-app>
```

Comment: What are the contents of your `WEB-INF/lib` directory on your webapp?  There's likely some conflicts there.

Comment: Just the jstl jar file:

Comment: Add your web.xml file to the question - or at least the relevant parts:  the `<web-app>' element for example.

Comment: I updated my original question with the web.xml, webdefault.xml and webdoc.xml files that are in the project area.